# Mocha chai request and express-session

Tags: session, request, mocha.js, chai

When using two nested chai requests, session get lost.

```
chai.request(server)
    .post('/api/v1/account/login')
    .send({_email: 'test@test.com', _password: 'testtest'})
    .end(function(err, res){
        chai.request(server)
        .get('/api/v1/user/me')
        .end(function(err2, res2){
            //here i should get the session, but its empty
            res2.should.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
    });
```

And i'm pretty sure that it's an error in my mocha test, because i tried it (the login and then retrieving the session) outside the test and the session is being setted.

Comment: Which method do you use to get the session? Can you add the `should` statement on session comparison?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't have a should statement on session comparison. Instead i have a middleware on my "/api/v1/user/" route: isAuthenticated: function (req, res, next) {

     var sess = req.session;
  if(!sess.user)
         return next();

     res.status(500).send({error:true})
 }   . So if no session, i expect this to return a status 500. And if session is setted i expect a status 200. But i am always getting 500.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

express itself does not have any native session support. I guess you are using some session middleware such as https://github.com/expressjs/session.

Meanwhile, I guess you are using chai-http plugin to send HTTP request. In chai-http, in order to retain cookies between different HTTP requests (so that req.session can be available in express side), you need to use `chai.request.agent` rather than `chai`.

Here is a simple example for your code:

```
var agent = chai.request.agent(app);
agent.post('/api/v1/account/login')
     .send({_email: 'test@test.com', _password: 'testtest'})
     .then(function(res){
             agent.get('/api/v1/user/me')
                  .then(function(res2){
                      // should get status 200, which indicates req.session existence.
                      res2.should.have.status(200);
                      done();
     });
});
```

For `chai.request.agent`, you can refer to http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/#retaining-cookies-with-each-request

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this issue, this approach worked for me using Mocha:

```
it("should...", () => {
  return agent.post('/api/v1/account/login')
    .send({_email: 'test@test.com', _password: 'testtest'})
    .then(async res => {
      const res2 = await agent.get('/api/v1/user/me')
      res2.should.have.status(200);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
});
```